# Laravel 5 accessing global variable in mail.php

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I need to set admin email in many place. so I created constants.php in config folder.

```
<?php
return array(
    'admin_email' =>'joe@doe.com',
    'admin_name' =>'Admin',
);
```

I was able to access this in my routes.php

```
dd(Config::get('constants.admin_email'));
```

However, when I try to access it in mail.php by

```
'from' => [
    'address' => Config::get('constants.admin_email'), 
    'name' => Config::get('constants.admin_name')
],
```

I got Class 'Config' not found in mail.php.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: have you try \Config with back slash??

Comment: Just tried, same error

Comment: Why are you defining configuration values in one configuration file just to retrieve them in another? Just define the values in your **config/mail.php** file.

Comment: I also need this in other place.

Comment: @daolincheng So use `Config::get('mail.from.address')` in that other place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing, I've found you can't use `Config`, `\Config` or `config()` in any files in your `config` folder. I believe they are not available to any of these files, but I'm not 100% sure why this is.

Regardless, to solve this issue and still have them available in other parts of your application, use `env` or environment variables. In your `.env` file, add the following:

```
ADMIN_EMAIL=joe@doe.com
ADMIN_NAME=Admin
```

Then, in your `mail.php` and anywhere else you want to use them, access them using:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('ADMIN_EMAIL'), 
    'name' => env('ADMIN_NAME')
],
```

You can actually see them already in use in your `mail.php` and other `config` files, so it makes sense to use what already works. Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
config('constants.admin_email');
```

Comment: `config()` and `Config::get()` are the same thing.

Comment: Using config() instead of using the facade rules out the possible namespacing error.